# Is possible to add prefix after docker port

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm working with docker container to host my angular 4 project. I have nginx server inter-mediating my client and my API. Failing to find way to access my front-end with something like this localhost/coffee.

Instead of recommended way of accessing docker 
`127.0.0.1:9000`

after 
`docker run -p 9000:80 image`,

am i able to do it this way for 
`127.0.0.1:9000/coffee` 
after

```
docker run -p 9000/coffee:80 image.
```

I have access to location, localhost/coffee which is opened on port 9000 on live server. I need to add prefix coffee on my exposed port docker port.

Comment: Post you nginx config also

Answer (score 3):

You can not add prefix after docker port.You can map port only.
To access frontend like localhost/coffee, you can configure nginx to handle this scenario(configure location as /coffee and proxy request to your backend server).

Answer (score 0):

@Girdhar Sojitra are right. You need to use nginx as reverse proxy. I wanna to add some notice. [Jwilder nginx-proxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy/)  can automatically configure subdomains for each of your backends.

Answer (score 0):

Port and request urls are two different things. Ports are meant for network communication and request urls are meant for webserver. So when you run

```
docker run -p 9000:80 image
```

If you are getting the app served on `localhost:9000` and you need to change it to `localhost:9000/coffee` this change needs to go in your code or in your web server config and not in the docker run command.

A simple nginx config for that would

```
http{
server {
   listen 80;

   location /coffee/ {
       proxy_pass http://yourbackendcontainer:backendport/;
   }
}
```

If you need `/coffee/` also to be passed as the part of the url to your backend then you would change the config to below

```
http{
server {
   listen 80;

   location /coffee {
       proxy_pass http://yourbackendcontainer:backendport;
   }
}
```